# Why should we strive to be the least immoral?

Tags: ethics

Assuming that we are all immoral because we have done at least one immoral thing in our "lifetime," why should we not do more immoral things? At the end of the day, we would still be immoral

Comment: It's fairly straightforward to see if you already can identify and know what's moral and what's immoral as a moral agent, so can easily known by others too. If you do many immoral things in an uncontrollable way, very quickly you'll receive counter actions and fall into troubles in no time...

Comment: By definition, moral behavior is what we ought to do, so you are asking why we ought to do what we ought to do.

Comment: This reminds me "the more we know the more we forget and the more we forget the less we know, so why study". This sort of thing is called the [continuum fallacy](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Continuum_fallacy): a quality that comes in grades is reduced to a binary, and all sorts of funny conclusions follow. If I cut off one finger I'll never have a full set of fingers again, so why not just go ahead and cut off the rest.

Comment: Desiring to be held in high esteem by others, or to hold yourself in high esteem, is a valid reason to be moral. But morality is a spectrum, not binary. You can be relatively more moral or relatively less moral, without being perfectly moral or immoral. There's always the next step up on the ladder, striving to be more moral so you can think of yourself as a better person, while accepting that you may never be *perfectly* moral.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental question here is not so much about morality, but rather focused on the common desire to be labelled as good or moral, or at least to avoid being labelled as bad or immoral. Per the human tendency toward competition for status and its resultant access to resources, our egoistic side prefers to derail opponents whenever possible; and what better way than to push others into the out-group using fallacies and slippery slopes.

With a tendency so common, a defence strategy was in order. One fairly common strategy is *vice signalling*, or showing the world how tough or rebellious one is, sometimes to the point of intentionally breaking moral norms. Vice signalling is essentially virtue signalling to the out-group, or making the out-group one's in-group. Another common strategy, as mentioned in the question, is to take loss of purity all the way. If the bad label is already present, then perhaps the most beneficial path involves complete anti-conformity to that value.

The cause for this phenomenon when reflecting upon oneself is thinking in labels, or internalising society's ruthless game of social status. If one's priority is to play the game, then one might have to accept a few lies here and there. To view oneself only through the lens of society is to miss the opportunity to develop one's own eyes. To understand morality is to see one's true nature and how it fits within the greater system.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to act in moral ways is because we want everyone else to also act in moral ways, not to steal from us, hurt us, kill us. It's an agreement with society.

Now if society decided that it will not treat you well no matter what, then indeed acting moral seems pointless, which is a justification for many criminals who see no chance of beginning accepted by society.

But in general, just because you stole a cookie from your grandma when you were 6 years old will not make society treat you as a criminal for life, so the majority of people in society are well accepted even if they are known to behave somewhat immoral now and then.